# Why does switching to secure folder (httpsdocs) break the PHP file upload function

Tags: php, ssl, apache-2.4, unix, upload

**Server version: Apache/2.4.34 (Unix)**

I'm trying to utilize an existing SSL certificate for several sub-directories of a domain, but the architecture for the domain separates out two directories for non-secure/secure:

```
httpdocs
httpsdocs
```

I copied everything from httpdocs to httpsdocs and also forced traffic to https using .htaccess. Everything worked great until I tried the PHP file upload functionality.

Here's the bit of code that is failing from the secure side:

```
$path = "uploaded_files/".$row_query[0].'/'.$file_name;
copy($temp_file, $path);
```

In doing some debugging, I found that the temp file gets created:
/tmp/phpanKT4N

but the error I see in the logs is:
copy(uploaded_files/New Sub Folder/30052_testing.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpsdocs/demo/resource/add_resource.php on line 108

I tried changing copy() to move_uploaded_file() but here's the error for that:

```
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(uploaded_files/test/30054_testing.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/<thedomain>.com/httpsdocs/demo/resource/add_resource.php on line 111
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpOC9YEF' to 'uploaded_files/test/30054_testing.txt' in /var/www/vhosts/<thedomain>.com/httpsdocs/demo/resource/add_resource.php on line 111
```

I searched stack and saw that ownership must match, but the permissions appear to be the same for httpdocs and httpsdocs.

The /tmp folder is owned by root:root and like I said this works perfectly from the non-secure folder. The non-secure and secure upload folders are identical:

httpdocs:

```
drwxrwxr-x+  8 theuser apache  4096 Sep 22  2015 uploaded_files
```

httpsdocs:

```
drwxrwxr-x+  8 theuser apache  4096 Sep 22  2015 uploaded_files
```

Is this a configuration, permissions issue, or what?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out... Ran the following:

First find apache's user:

```
egrep -i '^user|^group' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Result:
User apache
Group apache

Then ran this and it solved all the PHP file upload issues in httpsdocs:

```
chown -R apache:apache /var/www/vhosts/<thedomain>.com/httpsdocs/
chmod -R g+rw /var/www/vhosts/<thedomain>.com/httpsdocs/
```